# d3js Don't animate first enter

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've got sliding bar display that I'm trying to animate. Basically, there are two bars next to each other horizontally, each taking up a percentage of the total width. As the numbers change, the width and x position animate to reflect a new percentage.

It's working fine, except that I don't want an animation when the item first loads, only when the numbers change. Right now, it shoots into place from the left side of the item.

edit2: Here's the first version in a snippet:

```js
const d3SlidingBar = {};
//  data should simply be an array with two numbers
//  future: add support for arbitrary number of numbers
d3SlidingBar.create = function create(el, data, formatText) {
  const svg = d3.select(el).append('svg')
    .attr('class', 'sliding-bar__svg')
    .attr('width', '100%')
    .attr('height', '100%');

  svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'sliding-bar__svg__bars')
  //  try 100% here. Should work.
    .attr('width', el.offsetWidth)
    .attr('height', el.offsetHeight);

  if (data) this.update(el, data, formatText);
};

d3SlidingBar.update = function update(el, data, formatText) {
  // Re-compute the scales, and render the data points
  const scales = this.scale(el, data);
  this.drawBars(el, scales, data);
  this.drawNumbers(el, scales, data, formatText);
};

d3SlidingBar.scale = (el, data) =>
  d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([0, el.offsetWidth])
  .domain([0, data.reduce((a, b) => a + b)]);


d3SlidingBar.drawBars = (el, scale, data) => {
  const t = d3.transition()
    .duration(450);

  const barHeight = el.offsetHeight;

  //  keep track of right side of stacks of bar so bars can stack further.
  //  Useful if we have more than two bars.
  let greatestWidth = 0;

  const g = d3.select(el).selectAll('.sliding-bar__svg__bars');

  const bar = g.selectAll('.sliding-bar__svg__bar')
    .data(data);

  bar.enter().append('rect')
    .attr('class', (point, ind) => `sliding-bar__svg__bar sliding-bar__svg__bar--${ind}`)
    .attr('height', barHeight)
    .merge(bar)
    .transition(t)
    .attr('width', point => scale(point))
    .attr('x', (point) => {
      const oldGreatestWidth = greatestWidth;
      greatestWidth += scale(point);
      return oldGreatestWidth;
    });

  bar.exit().remove();
};

//  This function needs an overhaul, but I'm not sure how
d3SlidingBar.drawNumbers = (el, scale, data, formatText = point => point) => {
  const barHeight = el.offsetHeight;

  //  keep track of right side of stacks of bar so bars can stack further.
  //  Bar position is used to position text

  const g = d3.select(el).selectAll('.sliding-bar__svg__bars');

  const number = g.selectAll('.sliding-bar__svg__number')
    .data(data);

  number.enter().append('text')
    .style('font-size', barHeight - 10)
    .attr('y', barHeight - 10)
    .attr('class', (point, ind) => `sliding-bar__svg__number sliding-bar__svg__number--${ind}`)
    .merge(number)
    .attr('y', barHeight - 10)
    .style('font-size', barHeight - 10)
    .text(point => formatText(point))
    .attr('x', function xPosition(point, ind) {
      return (ind % 2) ?
        el.offsetWidth - this.getComputedTextLength() - 8
        : (0 + 8);
    });

  // This is for if we want the number to stay at the left of each bar,
  // const greatestWidth = 0;
  //
  //  ...number.enter...
  //
  // useful for more than 2 bars.
  // .attr('x', (point, ind) => {
  //   const oldGreatestWidth = greatestWidth;
  //   greatestWidth += scale(point);
  //   return oldGreatestWidth + 5;
  // })
  //

  number.exit().remove();
};


let count = 0;
const data = [[50, 50], [75,25]];
const formatText = text => `%${text}`;

const bars = document.getElementById('bars')

d3SlidingBar.create(bars, data[0], formatText)

setInterval(() => {
  count++;
  d3SlidingBar.update(bars, data[count % 2], formatText)
}, 1000)
```

```css
.sliding-bar__container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
}

.sliding-bar__svg__bars {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.sliding-bar__svg__bar--0 {
  fill: #33708E;
}

.sliding-bar__svg__bar--1 {
  fill: #CF8D3A;
}

.sliding-bar__svg__number {
  fill: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="sliding-bar__container" id='bars'>
  </div>
</body>
```

edit: I tried changing it to this, but now every time it updates, the bars shoot on from the right side...

```
d3SlidingBar.drawBars = (el, scale, data) => {
  const t = d3.transition()
    .duration(450);

  const barHeight = el.offsetHeight;

  //  keep track of right side of stacks of bar so bars can stack further.
  //  Useful if we have more than two bars.
  let greatestWidth = 0;
  let greatestWidthEnter = 0;

  const g = d3.select(el).selectAll('.sliding-bar__svg__bars');

  const bar = g.selectAll('.sliding-bar__svg__bar')
    .data(data);

  bar.transition(t)
    .attr('width', point => scale(point))
    .attr('x', (point) => {
      const oldGreatestWidth = greatestWidth;
      greatestWidth += scale(point);
      return oldGreatestWidth;
    });


  bar.enter().append('rect')
    .attr('class', (point, ind) => `sliding-bar__svg__bar sliding-bar__svg__bar--${ind}`)
    .attr('height', barHeight)
    .merge(bar)
    .attr('width', point => scale(point))
    .attr('x', (point) => {
      const oldGreatestWidth = greatestWidthEnter;
      greatestWidthEnter += scale(point);
      return oldGreatestWidth;
    });

  bar.exit().remove();
};
```

Comment: Could you change your code to a StackExchange snippet so we can execute it? It's difficult to visualize what's going on.

Comment: OK, done! Notice how on first load there is an animation from the left. I'd rather there be no animation on first load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I figured it out.

```
  bar
    .transition(t)
    .attr('width', point => scale(point))
    .attr('x', (point) => {
        const oldGreatestWidth = greatestWidth;
        greatestWidth += scale(point);
        return oldGreatestWidth;
    });




bar.enter().append('rect')
    .attr('class', (point, ind) => `sliding-bar__svg__bar sliding-bar__svg__bar--${ind}`)
    .attr('height', barHeight)
    .attr('width', point => scale(point))
    .attr('x', (point) => {
      const oldGreatestWidth = greatestWidth;
      greatestWidth += scale(point);
      return oldGreatestWidth;
    });
```

Basically, it was my second attempt, but removing the merge(bar) line. I am not sure what merge() does but it doesn't seem to be necessary for anything I'm doing. I thought it was required any time we used the update pattern but it's working fine without it.

I think it still works if merge(bar) is at the end of the enter() block, and not in the middle.